# Extract element by line starting with a specific character

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, data-cleaning

I'm currently working on this DataFrame python :
[image: Extract data frame]

The data-set has one column and n lines.

I would like to extract specifics components of specifics line, for exemple :

*For each line i starting with 'n', store in variable x the second element of the line i.*

or

*For each line i starting with 'e', store in variable x the second and third element of the line i.*

I would like to know which function/operation I can use for this problem.

Comment: please provide what have u tired and the sample output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create simple example:

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['aaaak', 'k jhs', 'anhdga', 'kjdhs']})
```

You can use column.str and see a first letter:

```
data.a.str[0]
```

**out:**

```
0    a
1    k
2    a
3    k
```

And you can check what the letter is:

```
data.a.str[0] == 'a'
```

**out:**

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
```

You can call raws with only first letter 'a':

```
data[data.a.str[0] == 'a']
```

**out:**

```
        a
0   aaaak
2  anhdga
```

And then you can get another letter in raws which started from 'a':

```
data[data.a.str[0] == 'a'].a.str[2]
```

**out:**

```
0    a
2    h
```